# Can't add a new field in migration: "column .. does not exist"

Tags: django, django-models, migration, django-south

I want to add a field to my model but I'm completely lost here. This is the model, the app name is called "profiles":

```
class Profiles(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, null=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True)  # new field
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
```

So, I added the "nickname" field. Then I ran

```
python manage.py schemamigration profiles --auto
python manage.py migrate profiles
```

But it gave me an error. "relation profiles_profiles already exists."

So I did

```
python manage.py migrate profiles --fake
python manage.py migrate profiles
```

and then when I try to work with the model I get the error

```
ProgrammingError: column profiles_profiles.nickname does not exist
```

The message I get when I try to migrate is:

```
"nothing to migrate"
and 
"nothing seems to have changed"
```

when I try to do a schemamigration and a migration. :/ ?¿.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: How did you solve this problem? It is almost exactly the situation I'm in and your question is the closest I've found describing my problem.

Comment: What I did is completely remake the db, erase the migration history and folders.

Answer (score 3):

The correct command would be:

```
python manage.py schemamigration <app_name> --auto
```

You've to write the name of the *app*, not of the *model*.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, just corrected it: The app is called "profiles" and the model is "Profiles". So yes, I use the correct command.